# Method that will return a boolean with the answer

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Im my homework I need to writhe a method that will return a boolean with the answer whether the given array of ints passed in the argument is sorted (example signature public boolean isSorted (int [] array))
Can someone try to help with this?
I'm not sure about the code but I'm start with that

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] a)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < a.length -1; i ++);{
    if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
        return false;
    }
        return true;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int ar[] = {3,5,6,7};
    System.out.println(isSorted(ar));
}
}
```

Comment: If you had a series of integers on a paper, how would you check if it's sorted?

Comment: If you remove the ``return true`` outside the for-loop, it should be alright.

Comment: It's considered rude to edit your question so an answer is invalidated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to sound rude

Answer (score 0):

`isSorted` and `isAscending` mean the same thing - one of these two booleans needs to go away.

The initial `a[1] > a[0]` is also unneccessary; you need to apply that principle (is element at position X lesser than element at position X+1) for every element except the last in the entire list.

The for loop is good, just move that check inside, using `i`.

Finally, to return a result, all you need is `return isSorted;`.

Comment: I'm guessing the assignment wants to check for an array that is sorted either way, ascending or descending.

Comment: actually no. Method return a boolean with the answer whether the given array of ints passed in the argument is sorted

Comment: my method still missing answer  whether the given array of ints passed in the argument is sorted, isn't it??